# SetLayeredWindowAttributes error when used on Tkinter Canvas Item when compiled by PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

---

I am creating an overlay HUD for a game using transparent Tkinter windows.

SetLayeredWindowAttributes is throwing up an error explaining "The parameter is incorrect". But this only happens in the compiled version of the program using PyInstaller. If I launch it from PyCharm, the code works perfectly.

```
canvas = Canvas(root, width = prereswidth, height = preresheight, bg = 'black', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.master.overrideredirect(True)
canvas.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
canvas.master.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
canvas.master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "black")
canvas.pack()


hwnd = root.winfo_id()  # getting hwnd with Tkinter windows
lExStyle = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
lExStyle = win32con.WS_EX_COMPOSITED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, lExStyle)


hwnd2 = canvas.winfo_id()
lExStyle = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd2, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
lExStyle = win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_COMPOSITED | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | win32con.WS_EX_TOPMOST | win32con.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE
win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd2, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, lExStyle)
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd2, RGB(0, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

I believe my issue here could be something to do with how Tkinter canvas items work. I've tried everything I can think of and Googled for hours and hours. I'm at my wits end with this one.